# Why I get double access records for every access in the access log?

Tags: http

When I check the access log , I found that there are two access records for every access like this:

```
210.254.134.38 - - [24/Jul/2015:11:02:12 +0900] "GET /glico/arianagrandesweepstakes HTTP/1.1" 200 13544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36" "-" "0.013"
210.254.134.38 - - [24/Jul/2015:11:02:12 +0900] "GET /glico/arianagrandesweepstakes HTTP/1.0" 200 13516 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36" "0.013"
```

The difference between these two records is that they have different HTTP versions(HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1)

Can anyone please explain me the possible reasons?